# VariableSizedWrapGrid does not size correctly if control size modified in code

Tags: xaml, resize, uwp, variablesizedwrapgrid

I am creating a UWP app and I am using the VariableSizedWrapGrid control.  I am binding the Width of the a ComboBox in the grid to it the ComboBox width resizes based on the entries in the list.  ( I am using a simple property exposed through my view model.)  When I had the items in a StackPanel with a Horizontal orientation it worked fine.  See picture below

[image: Screen Shot using StackPanel]

The challenge of course is that on a smaller screen I need the fields to wrap around.  So I switched the StackPanel to a VariableSizedWrapGrid.  However, when I do that, the Grid does not seem to be handling the resizing of the ComboBox correctly as I get what is shown below.  (See the ComboBox is now cut off

[image]

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happen if you set the HorizontalAlignment of the Combobox to Stretch?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong Panel for the job. The one you're looking for is a WrapPanel (which doesn't exist actually though), but there are some implementations available, eg.: http://codepaste.net/8gr5go

Comment: I am not using a panel.  The problem is with VariableSizedWrapGrid which is the correct control to use for this in Windows Universal Apps as far as I can tell.  I want to know why the VariableSizedWrapGrid is not working correctly when I resize my combobox's width via a bound property.

Comment: I have reported the problem to Microsoft and I am waiting for further information.  I will post it when it appears.

Comment: Did you hear anything back yet from MS?

Comment: I have not heard anything back from MS yet